# Operator overloading in C++ and the ampersand

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the ampersand for when used after class name like ostream& operator <<(…)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572016/whats-the-ampersand-for-when-used-after-class-name-like-ostream-operator)

I am new to C++ and I have probably a very noobish question. I have seen a thing like this:

```
Vector3f & operator = (Vector3f & obj)
{
    _item[0] = obj[0];
    _item[1] = obj[1];
    _item[2] = obj[2];

    return *this;
}
```

And I was wondering why is there an ampersand (&) after Vector3f. What kind of magic is it doing? I couldn't find any explanations anywhere. Most importantly, what is the difference between the thing above and

```
Vector3f operator = (Vector3f obj)
{
    _item[0] = obj[0];
    _item[1] = obj[1];
    _item[2] = obj[2];

    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's C++'s syntax for pass-by-reference & return-by-reference. It just means that the parameter is an alias of the object from the calling context, and not a copy, and, simillary, the returned object is actually `*this`, and not a copy.

Comment: So is it like passing a pointer to the object? So why didn't they pass a pointer rather than a reference?

Comment: @MartinMarinov because it's C++ and not C. References provide different syntax & semantics. If you don't know what they are, I suggest you read a good introductory C++ book.

Answer (score 2):

The first one takes a `Vector3f` by refetence, and returns a `Vec3torf` by reference. The second takes and returns by value (i.e. semantically it makes a copy of the argument as well as `*this`).